# I'm not getting response from my jsonp

Tags: javascript, json, html, jsonp

i have this test json url

[This is the link](http://jsfiddle.net/FUWyJ/7/)

```
 jQuery.support.cors = true;

window.Getdata = function() {
  var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: "{}",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "/gh/gist/response.json/4001105/",
    mimeType: "application/json; cherset=utf-8",
    success: krywaarde,
    failure: givealert
  });

  function krywaarde(result) {
    alert("Name = "+result.fighters[0].name);
    alert("Nickname = "+result.fighters[0].nickname);
    // this changes the text
    document.getElementById("routing").innerHTML = result.fighters[0].name;
  }

  function givealert(error) {
    alert('failed!!' + error);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  window.Getdata();
});
​
```

**i have edited my whole questions code**

the  problem i have now is, it works on JSFiddle, but not in my mobile app.
the onlu changes between the 2 is, the ons on Js Fiddle is called on page load, and my real mobile app the function is called on buttonclick!

here is the jsfiddle :

[little jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FUWyJ/7/)

the html where i am calling the function is

```
<a type=button id="processnames" onclick="window.Getdata();" style="color: White; font-size:large;">test json
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
kryrequest(https://raw.github.com/appcelerator/Documentation-Examples/master/HTTPClient/data/json.txt?callback=awe)
```

… looks like it is trying to pass a string literal to the function. String literals must be surrounded by **quote marks**.

*(this section refers to an earlier version of the question)*

---

Additionally, that URI returns a JSON text, not a JSONP script, so it still won't work if you do fix that.

---

What's more, even if that response did contain JSON-P, it will wouldn't work because the object has a `fighters` property, but not a `name` property. The value of `fighters` **is** an array (of objects which have `names`), but those names are strings, not arrays.

*(this section refers to an earlier version of the question)*

Comment: well thanks i guess, i said i am new to this, so the whole "007" approach not cool , i'm asking for help how to get around this, not to be crucified by a pro!

Comment: @Arrie — So you *don't* want us to tell you where you have gone wrong?

Comment: i understand that you told me what i have done wrong, but you also didn't really tell me what i should do to get this working? and i edited my question's code for the bit you gave me i am confused seeing as this is my 2nd day working with json and javascript!

Comment: @Arrie — 1. Put quotes around your strings. 2. Request a URL that returns JSONP not JSON. 3. Access the properties of the data structure you actually get back.

Comment: okay, but cant i get the json result back this way?the thing is, i dont care for what type of data return(json or jsonp), i just need that i get that string to show on a page on a button click, with all the fighters name's in its own container, if you get what im saying

Comment: If you want to get json data instead of jsonp data you need to proxy it through the same server you're serving the html file from. This is because you can only make AJAX requests from the same domain name as the HTML file due to same-origin policy.

Comment: @Arrie — No. If you want to get data by generating `<script>` elements then you have to get JSONP data, not JSON data.

Comment: @@slebetman - so you saying i must use ajax to get the json back ?

Comment: @Arrie — Ajax just means "Using JS to make an HTTP request and process the response without leaving the page". Your existing code is Ajax. If you want to get data from a different origin you have to use JSONP or CORS. The alternative is to set up your system so you can get the data from the same origin, then you can use XMLHttpRequest without CORS.

Comment: i have edited my answer , i think this is a better approach maybe? it works on jsfiddle, but i get no response from my mobile applicaition